# Website Question:  Use of Gravatar

Tags: discussion

I was going to change my avatar today, and realized again why it was still the site default - Gravatar.  I don't know about everybody else, but I really don't want to have anything else to sign up for and log in to on every site.

Is there any way we can use both Gravatar and a traditional avatar image source - either stored on the site, or linked to an external source?

Thanks for the hard work keepoing SSD running!

Comment: Ya, you need to use Gravatar if you want a customized pic. It's for the better though. Really ;-) It's great if you have an online presence in more than one spot, and want your pic to come up whenever you even just comment. It's worth it.

Comment: Do you have to be signed in to gravatar at all times?  Work clears my browser whenever I close it, so I guess I'd have to sign in every time I opened IE.  

Comment: There is now a way to set [a separate profile image, not dependant on Gravatar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/41278).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see your point, but I thought that was the whole point of Gravatar, so that you didn't have to sign up for anything else. After uploading my avatar to Gravatar, my face keeps popping up on pages that I post on, but don't remember signing up for or logging in to (that may be a deterrent to some). Maybe I'm wrong about that, there's just too many pages out there these days. I can't keep them all straight.

If nothing else, I like knowing that my avatar is out there in a central location where I can pull it (or change it) once, instead of having to worry about all the different sites that I've uploaded pics to.

Answer (score 1):

I signed up for Gravatar, uploaded a picture, and still havent figured out how to get it to link to this account. If it does it automatically, its not working for me.

Comment: @C3Sound You sure you used the same email address for both your gravatar account and your SSD account? 

Comment: @Andrew Apparently I had multiple emails set up for my Gravatar picture - this brings the dilemma of me using my ccc@c3sound.com email for sound design related things, and my other for everything else. I cant only make 1 primary - this sort of defeats the purpose of using the service - but ill use it just for SSD anyways.

Comment: It normally takes a little time for the gravatar to start working.  This is normal.  I think it has to do with caching or some such.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a way to set [a separate profile image, not dependant on Gravatar or Facebook](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/41278). This image is set directly in your profile here: it does not come from an external resource. Similarly, it can be edited here.

If you do not set one, it falls back to Gravatar as before. (Or Facebook, if your initial login was from Facebook.)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to remain logged in to gravatar.  You log in to gravatar to change the avatar, but the actual image tied to your id is public, so SE just needs to store the ID of your avatar and can always access it.  This makes sense intuitively since other people can access your gravatar image even when you are not online, though it doesn't necessarily jump out at you immediately.